# Error loading Data into MongoDB with double quotes in the data

Tags: json, mongodb, csv, import

I have data where the data has double quotes in the string, example - Location: America"s.  We have data both in json and csv.

For the dataset, I changed one data in the restaurants data from the sample dataset from Mongodb. Below the dataset

{"address": {"building": "1007", "coord": [-73.856077, 40.848447], "street": "Morris Park Ave", "zipcode": "10462"}, "borough": "Bronx", "cuisine": "Bakery", "grades": [{"date": {"$date": 1393804800000}, "grade": "A", "score": 2}, {"date": {"$date": 1378857600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 6}, {"date": {"$date": 1358985600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 10}, {"date": {"$date": 1322006400000}, "grade": "A", "score": 9}, {"date": {"$date": 1299715200000}, "grade": "B", "score": 14}], "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop", "restaurant_id": "30075445"}
{"address": {"building": "469", "coord": [-73.961704, 40.662942], "street": "Flatbush" Avenue", "zipcode": "11225"}, "borough": "Brooklyn", "cuisine": "Hamburgers", "grades": [{"date": {"$date": 1419897600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 8}, {"date": {"$date": 1404172800000}, "grade": "B", "score": 23}, {"date": {"$date": 1367280000000}, "grade": "A", "score": 12}, {"date": {"$date": 1336435200000}, "grade": "A", "score": 12}], "name": "Wendy'S", "restaurant_id": "30112340"}
{"address": {"building": "351", "coord": [-73.98513559999999, 40.7676919], "street": "West   57 Street", "zipcode": "10019"}, "borough": "Manhattan", "cuisine": "Irish", "grades": [{"date": {"$date": 1409961600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 2}, {"date": {"$date": 1374451200000}, "grade": "A", "score": 11}, {"date": {"$date": 1343692800000}, "grade": "A", "score": 12}, {"date": {"$date": 1325116800000}, "grade": "A", "score": 12}], "name": "Dj Reynolds Pub And Restaurant", "restaurant_id": "30191841"}

When I try to import into MongoDB, it errors out 
2016-07-10T10:28:10.377-0400    Failed: error processing document #2: invalid character 'A' after object key:value pair

We can't change / remove the double quotes from the data, since it has to be stored as it is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the data you are trying to insert is not valid json. It's missing : at many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to make sure JSON data is valid first, before inserting it (are you using MongoDB command line btw?
Make sure you to escape your JSON data before inserting.

`"street": "Flatbush" Avenue"`

should become

`"street": "Flatbush\" Avenue"`

Hope that helps.